# Вызов процедуры Oracle (Hibernate)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, plsql, хранимые-процедуры

В БД есть процедура: `pkg_report.report_ds(:p_dat1, :p_dat2, ?)`. На вход она принимает даты, а выходной параметр `pkg_global.ref_cursor_type`.

Эта процедура в итоге выдает множество полей, которые я получаю из 5-6 таблиц.

Как вызвать эту процедуру с помощью `Hibernate`?

Процедура:

```
PROCEDURE report_ds (
p_dat1              IN DATE
,p_dat2             IN DATE
,rc1                IN OUT pkg_global.ref_cursor_type) AS

BEGIN

OPEN rc1 FOR

SELECT
*
FROM
....

END report_ds;
```

Comment: А что третьим параметром передается?

Comment: Это выходной параметр типа pkg_global.ref_cursor_type

Comment: Это надо убрать, иначе нельзя будет вызвать процедуру.

Comment: А если его убрать, то куда будет происходить выборка? В вопросе обновил как выглядит процедура. Я в Oracle не силен. Процедуру делал на основании другой похожей.

Comment: О какой выборке говоришь? Курсоры используются в PL/SQL, в Java используется ResultSet.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но вы говорите что мне из процедуры надо убрать параметр ,rc1 IN OUT pkg_global.ref_cursor_type. В таком случае куда будут выгружаться результаты? Или мне нужно в Java при вызове убрать третий параметр?

Comment: Результаты надо выгружать на экран.

Comment: Как это сделать?